# How to avoid putty's connection timeout

Tags: ssh, putty

I am using putty to test an m2m device. When I try testing the standby-mode I get an error saying that the software aborted the connection. By standby-mode I mean it literaly shuts down everything, except for some moduls, that can wake up the device. Therefor there the device is not able to communicate with putty at all. I know I could detach my process from the shell so it keeps running and then restart putty and connect again, but this seems like a lot of effort if I have to do this every time I wanna test it. The keep-alive option also does not solve my problem, since this only works when the device is idle, but still able to communicate. So is there any way to let putty wait until it receives data once again, or is it just not possible?

Comment: How exactly do you connect to the device? Over the regular network that stays connected? Or is it a link that goes down when the device enters sleep mode? Is the device entering sleep mode by itself or due to a command you send in PuTTY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Open Putty

-open “Connection” tab

-Under “Sending of null packets to keep session active – Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)”, enter a value in the textbox. for example 120 ( this is secound)

-Go to “Session” and save this as “Default Settings”.
every time you open putty, for new session read default Settings

Comment: To be fair, it kinda works if I set it to a really high value and hope the keepalive does not get send. But if I am unlucky it will get send and i have the same prroblem again. Maybe someone has a cleaner solution. If not, i will use this.

Comment: If you have task and dont want your task or session killed another way is use screen or tmux or ....
https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/amp/

Answer (score 0):

If you have task and dont want your task or session killed another way is use screen or tmux or ....
https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/amp/

Comment: This is pretty much the same as detatching my process from the shell. It works but it is not what i am looking for, since the connection still gets aborted